# Prevent focus change in form when pressing left/right keyboard keys on Android 7.1

Tags: xamarin.android

I have downloaded the source code of an open-source android app that is programmed in Xamarin.

The problem is that the app behaves differently on my Android Tablet (Android 7.1) in contrast to all other, newer android devices.

It's about a simple input form with

- E-Mail text field
- Password textfield
- OK button.

Only on the Android 7.1 device, I am able to jump around with the focus and switch between the three elements by pressing the arrow keys on a keyboard. And I don't want this behavior.
On the newer Android devices, the focus is locked and the arrow keys are only acting inside the active text field. Jumping between the three elements shall be only possible with the Tab key and not the arrow keys.

[This is an example file from the open-source project](https://github.com/bitwarden/mobile/blob/master/src/App/Pages/Accounts/LoginPage.xaml)

Please note that this is not my source code and I am just linking it here.

I'm new to Xamarin and I am expecting this to be configurable in the .xaml files?! But maybe I also need to overload a "Window_KeyDown" method or something? No idea and the different behavior for different android versions makes it not easier.